# JPanel to popuped from taskbar

Tags: swing

I want a JPanel  with conrols to be  pop-up ed from windows taskbar when My application started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you want a JDialog with controls to be popped up, since JPanel is not a top level container. Add a window listener to your top-level container (JFrame). It is fairly easy to implement your openMyControlsDialog(...) method:

```
addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
        openMyControlsDialog(evt);
    }
});
```

I do not quite understand what you mean when you write "from taskbar". Don't all programs pop up from the task bar?